# How do I fix HTML Javascript button not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently practicing a problem where I need to create a HTML page that accepts a string and returns any palindromes words however the button to initiate this task is not returning any result.

here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        enter your string: <input type="text" id="theString">
        <button id="find">Find Palindromes</button>
        <ul id="words"></ul>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("find").onclick = findClick;
};
function findClick() {
    document.getElementById("palindromes").innerHTML = "";
    var phraseList=document.getElementById("theString").value.split(" ");
    for (var j=0 ; j < phraseList.length ; i++) {
        if (checker(phraseList[j])) {
            var li=document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML=phraseList[i];
            document.getElementById("words").appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}
function checker(x) {
    x=x.toLowerCase();
    for (var i=0 ; i < s.length / 2 ; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[s.length - 1 - i]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? `document.getElementById("palindromes")` is null.

Comment: `s` is also undefined. Please check your code for syntax errors before we move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some typo in your code. I changed the `[i]` inside `findClick()` to `[j]` and `s` in `checker()` to `x`. I also commented the `document.getElementById('palindromes')` because there is no element with id `palindromes` in your HTML.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("find").onclick = findClick;
};

function findClick() {
    //document.getElementById("palindromes").innerHTML = "";
    var phraseList=document.getElementById("theString").value.split(" ");
    for (var j=0 ; j < phraseList.length ; j++) {
        if (checker(phraseList[j])) {
            var li=document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML=phraseList[j];
            document.getElementById("words").appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}

function checker(x) {
    x=x.toLowerCase();
    for (let i=0 ; i < x.length / 2 ; i++) {
        if (x[i] != x[x.length - 1 - i]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        enter your string: <input type="text" id="theString">
        <button id="find">Find Palindromes</button>
        <ul id="words"></ul>        
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried this code and this works well.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!! I changed the code multiple times so I got confused with the variables and stuff haha.